# How to synchronize the content of two laptops to display on screen?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, sync, display

I will have two laptops, each one in on a screen. I need a way when I do a change on a laptop, the change be reproduced in the another too because each one has a screen displaying the image.

There is a free software to do this? I think the laptops will be connected via wireless network.

Comment: Are you looking to simply mirror the displays, or do you need to replicate keyboard and mouse actions on the 2nd laptop?

Comment: @sblair Only mirror the display of one in the another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to have a VNC server running on one laptop in screen sharing mode, then run VNC client on the other laptop in full screen mode.

This is similar to RDP but both machines can see the same desktop.  Both laptops can control the mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Install teamviewer on one laptop, connect to it using the other one